# How to write code in java that sees whether or not a char is an int?

Tags: java, char, int, compare

I'm trying to write a method in java that takes a string and removes all the digits. To do this, I've converted the string into a char array. I have a for loop that runs through each char, but instead of having to compare the char to a 1, then to a 2, then 3, and so on, I want to see if there's any way of seeing if the char is an int.

```
public static String removeDigits(String s) {
    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
    String x = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        if (chars[i] == 1 || chars[i] == 2) {
            //remove the char
        }//etc
    }
}
```

I don't want to have to put chars[i] == 1,2,3,4,etc nine times. Is there a method to directly see if chars[i] is an int and systematically continue?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `Character.isDigit(chars[i])`.